# "gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory" on CentOS 6.7

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, centos6, bazel

I have a really strange thing going on on my computer. I did lookup for similar questions but the solutions there did not help me out.

I am trying to install bazel 0.2.2b on Cent OS 6.7. Bazel requires gcc 4.8 or higher to compile so I upgraded my gcc to 4.8.2 uisng the steps given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos).

I did an scl enable after the installation but nothing changed. My default gcc was still 4.4.7. SO I did the following steps:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc.bak
sudo cp /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc
sudo mv /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++.bak
sudo cp /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++
```

Since removing gcc was dangerous, i moved it to another file and copied the new one into /usr/bin/gcc.

Now, my default gcc and g++ are both 4.8.2 but I still get the error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

When I do `./compile` to install Bazel.

I tried solutions posted in other similar questions asking to upgrade/re-install 
but to no use.

```
$ yum install gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
You need to be root to perform this command.
[sree@ds1 bazel]$ sudo yum install gcc-c++
[sudo] password for sree:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: mirror.cs.princeton.edu
 * extras: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I am worried I might break the system core if I do anything wrong. What should I do now?

Comment: I don't know if all those private builds of devtoolset are OK. The well tested devtoolset´s from CERN never causes any trouble : http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset/ .... # `yum install devtoolset-2-gcc-c++` ....                      The enabling command is : $ `scl enable devtoolset-2 bash`

Comment: About `scl enable devtoolset-2 bash` : when you exit the terminal, the settings are gone. I.e. repeat the enable command if you open a new treminal session. .... About building bazel from source http://www.bazel.io/docs/install.html ... see the last chapter.

Answer (score 0):

---

CentOS 6.8 - 64bits :

The git versiom, `git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel.git` **fails**.

( `cd bazel/ && scl enable devtoolset-2 bash && sh compile.sh` )

And bazel-0.2.2b fails too.

---

The installer  bazel-0.3.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh works OK ...
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.3.0/bazel-0.3.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

```
su    
sh bazel-0.3.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
```

---

Comment: Thanks @Knud Larsen. But I need to install only one of the versions 0.2.0 - 0.2.2b since I have to ultimately run Syntaxnet on my machine.